# OkHttp Android post cause error JSON malformed

Tags: android, json, node.js

I am simply trying to craft a JSON object in the body of a request to my API in nodeJS. I keep getting this error on my server side:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1
```

Here is how i craft my request using OkHttpClient:

```
 String patientAddress = "0x83d0aa553df8bbf2c70c8250a1edbdef5be2ccbe";
        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, "{patientAddress:" + patientAddress + "}");

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.main_url) + "/api/getPatientDetails")
                .headers(buildStandardHeaders(Stormpath.accessToken()))
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

**EDIT**

Problem wast that i was not creating my JSON right, here is the working code:

```
String patientAddress = "0x83d0aa553df8bbf2c70c8250a1edbdef5be2ccbe";
        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, "{\"patientAddress\" :\"" + patientAddress + "\"}");

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.main_url) + "/api/getPatientDetails")
                .headers(buildStandardHeaders(Stormpath.accessToken()))
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

Comment: you could still accept the answer as it lead it you the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "{patientAddress:"

That's not valid JSON.

You need to quote the keys.

```
"{\"patientAddress\" :\"" + patientAddress + "\"}"
```

However, please use a proper JSON library to build JSON object strings

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("patientAddress", patientAddress);
```

Request with `params.toString()`

You can also use Retrofit over Okhttp to make Java objects from your API

Comment: why Retrofit over Okhttp ? and adding quotes did not help

Comment: You probably added them wrong. And because you would have access to Gson and not need to set the content type and parse raw strings yourself into Java objects. Retrofit uses Okhttp under the hood. It's much simpler for REST API usage.

Comment: i did it exactly how you said an i still get an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 20

Comment: You should still use the `new JSONObject` approach shown